# Sort data from structures in alphabetical order

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

I'm a bit annoyed. I can't find any solution that I could sort data from structures. Look, this is my code. I'll explain what's happening and what I'm trying to do:

(I had to translate the code from my native language to English so... if you find any weird words notice me.)

I'm trying to sort this structure of countries. But my mistake is that the only thing I'm sorting is the list of country names.. so the data will mess up. Can you help me with a good algorithm for this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int n;

struct Countries{
    char country_code[20];
    char country_name[20];
    float country_area;
    int country_people;
    float global_income;
}*countries;

void menu();
void read();
void display();
void sort();
void exit();

int main(){
    printf("Enter no of countries: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    countries = malloc(n * sizeof(*countries));
    menu();
}

void menu(){
    int op;
    printf("[1] Read;\n[2] Display;\n[3] Sort;\n[4] Exit.\n");
    printf(">> "); scanf("%d", &op); fflush(stdin);
    switch(op){
        case 1:
            read();
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            sort();
            break;
        case 4:
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void read(){
    printf("\n\n\n______READ______n\n\n");
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Country code #%d: ", i+1); gets(countries[i].country_code); fflush(stdin);
        printf("Country name: "); gets(countries[i].country_name); fflush(stdin);
        printf("Area: "); scanf("%f", &countries[i].country_area); fflush(stdin);
        printf("No of people: "); scanf("%d", &countries[i].country_people); fflush(stdin);
        printf("Global Income: "); scanf("%f", &countries[i].global_income); fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
    menu();
}
void display(){
    printf("\n\n\n______DISPLAY______n\n\n");
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Country code #%d: ", i+1); puts(countries[i].country_code);
        printf("Country name: "); puts(countries[i].country_name);
        printf("Area: "); printf("%.2f", countries[i].country_area);
        printf("\nNo of people: "); printf("%d", countries[i].country_people);
        printf("\nGlobal Income: "); printf("%.2f", countries[i].global_income);
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
}

void sort(){
    int i, j;
    char temp[20];
    /* countries sorted in alphabetical order */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(strcmp(countries[i].country_name, countries[j].country_name)>0){
                strcpy(temp,countries[i].country_name);
                strcpy(countries[i].country_name, countries[j].country_name);
                strcpy(countries[j].country_name, temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n\nCountry: "); puts(countries[i].country_name);

        printf("Population density: ");
        printf("%.2f", ((float)countries[i].country_people)/((float)countries[i].country_area));

        printf("\nIncome per people: ");
        printf("%.2f", ((float)countries[i].country_people)/((float)countries[i].global_income));
    }
}

void exit(){
    free(countries);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: So as you swap country data same thing do for other elements of structure. or simply copy whole structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your sort function, copy all of the structure rather than just the name

```
void sort(){
    struct Countries temp;
```

---

```
            if(strcmp(countries[i].country_name, countries[j].country_name)>0){
                //strcpy(temp, countries[i]);
                //strcpy(countries[i], countries[j]);
                //strcpy(countries[j], temp);
                temp = countries[i];
                countries[i] = countries[j];
                countries[j] = temp;
            }
```

Comment: I was looking for an algorithm. The ideea was good but.. what function should I use instead of strcpy? (which is for strings :D)

Comment: @CristianOnescu If you have structs use the assign operator, that is: `=`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just use plain assignment; post edited.